# Naming output file using more variables

Tags: r, csv, output

I'm using a write.csv statement to direct output to a file. I have several variables in the program: 'n', 'k' and 'temp'. For example: n=100, k=0.1 and temp=2000.

I would like for the output csv files to be labeled 'file name t 2000 N 100 k 01.csv'. But with the following command:

```
    write.csv(res, file = paste0("file name t", temp,".csv"),row.names=FALSE)
```

I can write only 'file name t 2000.csv'. How could I write the correct label? Thanks!

Comment: paste0("file name t", temp,"N",n,"k",k,".csv")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can string together as many things as you want in `paste0`:

```
paste0("file name t", temp, "N", n, "k", k, ".csv")
```

Though you may need to adjust the spacing to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

```
#'file name t 2000 N 100 k 01.csv'. 

a <- "file name t "
b <- 2000
c <- " N 100"
d <- " k 01"

write.csv(res, file = paste0(a, b, c, d, ".csv"),row.names=FALSE)
```